# Integer factorization: Why can't we use the test algorhitm to create an algorhitm to decide the factoring decision problem in polynomial time?

Tags: decision-problem

I'm reading Nielsen and Chuang. On page 142 the integer factoring decision problem is introduced: The integer factorization problem can be reduced to a decision problem:

Given a composite integer m and l < m, does m have a non-trivial
factor less than l?

For a given witness x < l this problem can be checked in polynomial time. Now I'm asking myself why it should not be possible to use the algorithm for checking to construct a polynomial time algorithm to decide the decision problem. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
for x < l
  if check(x,l,m)
     return true
  else 
     return false
```

This is basically just trying out all potential numbers of which there are at maximum m. So the time needed for this should be still linear because m times polynomial time (for the checking algorithm) should still be just polynomial I think.

I know something about this reasoning must be wrong but I'm completely stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution by myself: It is called Pseudo-polynomial time - the time scales polynomial in the value of the number but not in the length.

Comment: Indeed, integer division takes time polynomial in the value of the dividend and divisor, so by exhaustive division, factoring takes polynomial time in the value of the number to factor.

Comment: Actually, even faster than linear. Pollard-Rho is not the fastest anymore and can together with a fast primality tester factor a number around n in O (n^(1/4)). Unfortunately for an n-bit number that is about 2^(n/4).